# extend rails model into something else to keep integration code seperate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am integrating a rails app (rails 3 at the moment, moving to 5) with another application. The user model in the rails app will have associations that are related to the integration, scopes, and a bunch of methods.

I would like to separate these from the user model file to avoid cluttering it up and keep all the associations, scopes and methods related to the integration in a single place rather than watch the user model become cluttered with things only relevant to users with the integration enabled.

Is this possible, and if so, what mechanism would I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html):

```
module AdditionalLogic
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
    belongs_to :user
    # etc..
  end
  # other methods
end

class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AdditionalLogic
end
```

Comment: that looks ideal. Is it possible to put associations in the module? (so associations between user and other models)